# Consistency of Colorbox across browsers

Tags: jquery, cross-browser, colorbox, bigbluebutton

I have installed a BigBlueButton server, and it seems to work fine in that I
can access the BBB demo and also access it from a PHP application
using the BBB API.

The problem starts when I try to open the BBB client in a modal window
created using the Colorbox jQuery plug in using the iframe content type. It works as expected whenI use Firefox or Google Chrome in that the BBB client opens and the
user is joined to the meeting as either moderator or attendee.

**Problem 1:** When I try to do so in Internet Explorer or Safari, the
modal window does not open the BBB client. Instead it takes me to the
BBB demo page on my BBB server. And I cannot seem to join even the BBB
demo in the modal window. But it gets worse. I have added debugging
code to make sure that the url being used in the modal window to call
the BBB client is correct. If I  simply take this URL  and put it into
a new tab in Internet Explorer or Safari, then the BBB client opens as
expected. It just does not seem to be doing so in the modal window.

**Problem 2:** After I have accessed the BBB client using the URL in
another tab in the browser, when I reload my PHP application, and
access the page again, the BBB client will now load as expected in the
modal window generated with Colorbox. (So, the URL generated by the
BBB API is correct). This behavior is consistent for IE and Safari.)
So, for some reason, accessing the BBB client in browser tab seems to
be necessary before IE or Safari will allow me to access it in a modal
window generated by Colorbox. Also, note that once I have accessed a
BBB client in the browser tab, then I can access any meeting in the
modal window (not only the one which I had joined in the browser tab.)
When I close the browser and start it again, then accessing the BBB
client in the modal window does not work again. It seems that in the modal window generated by Colorbox, in IE and Safari, all the components of BBB are not able to load properly.

Please help. I have been trying to figure this out for a couple days
with no luck. Has anyone else had similar issues and have guidance for
resolving them?

Thanks very much.

Comment: For more discovery, what are you seeing in the console of either IE or Safari.  IE's is not the best, but even a bit of console log might help.  Additionally, you should be able to use the HTML page that serves as content to the iFrame on its own for testing. That might further help you to isolate the issue. What's more, edit your post once more to include whether the server is on a remote host,LAN or if you are accessing it over a simple file system call. Lastly, does the server track a log of attempted connections. I know nada of BBB but it's worth looking into. == KJM

Comment: don't know if this will help and it's not related to BBB but in the colorbox js settings try setting fastIframe:false.  This helped me fix an IE bug with Colorbox.

Answer (score 1):

tricky one are you calling the BBB IPI from a URL e.g. something like

```
<script src="www.bbb.com/script.js"></script>
```

or is it local

```
 <script src="js/bbb.js"></script>
```

if it is not a local scrip try and download it, i have had similar problems and this has fixed them, also if you are calling the API from another page

```
<?php include_once "bbb.html" ?>
```

make sure that the script hook is on the calling page and the called page. it shouldn't matter on live app but it sometimes does.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Enabling some of the IE security settings? I would set the domain as a trusted site then change your settings for trusted sites to a custom level.

Some of the settings that may help:

- Access data sources across domains - Enable
- Launching programs and files in an IFRAME - Enable
- Navigate windows and frames across different domains - Enable

Comment: The problems happen the *same in both IE and Safari*, so this is not a good answer.